# iphone: expand and collapse a UIView programmatically

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am very new to iPhone/iPad development.
can you please help me create this programmatically. I want to expand/collapse a UIView programmatically.

This expandable/collapsable view will have some text field and lables which should appear and disappear with that view

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose you have a UIView instance in the UIViewController class like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w1, h1)];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

based on the requirement you set the view visibility as I did here .. I am not displaying the view when the controller is loading it's view ..

```
[view setHidden:YES];
```

Maintain a flag to check the visibility of the view instance .. lets say `isViewVisible` is my flag to check the visibility of the view .. I set it to NO in the begning ..

```
isHelpViewVisible = NO;
```

and I wrote an action method (viewClicked) here to expand and to collapse the view object , give this action method to a button instance and it will work.

```
- (void)viewClicked:(id)sender {

    if (!isViewVisible) {
        isViewVisible = YES;
        [view setHidden:NO];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationOff" context:NULL]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.3f];
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w1, h1)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        isViewVisible = NO;
        [view setHidden:NO];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationOff" context:NULL]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.3f];
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, hight)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}
```

and add the textfields and labels objects to the view object as subviews and set the animation to those objects as well .. it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Replaces the following from above:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animationOff" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.3f];
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w1, h1)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

With the New way of doing animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.3f animations:^{
    self.frame = CGRectMake( x1, x2, w1, h1);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // this gives us a nice callback when it finishes the animation :)
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the size / position of a UIView within its parent just change its frame property:

```
CGRect newFrame = myView.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = newX;
newFrame.origin.y = newY;
newFrame.size.width = newWidth;
newFrame.size.height = newHeight;
myView.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
CGRect frame = [currentView frame];
frame.size.width = 999;//Some value
frame.size.height = 444;//some value
[currentView setFrame:frame];
```

You can follow this whenever you want to increase/decrease view size