# Need tutorials for animation in Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can anyone please provide me the tutorial for animation samples in iPad?

Comment: Be more specific of what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Terente,I just want to animate the UIView like (expanding the view,Shrinking the View) Is there any way to do this using the inbuilt animations in ipad sdk??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended Reading for iPhone Core Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907068/recommended-reading-for-iphone-core-animation)

Answer (score 0):

See the following

- [**Video tutorial**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?playnext=1&index=0&feature=PlayList&v=-dJJgUqCH0w&list=PLE97B882FB8C8C0D6).
- [**Expand and collapse animation for UITableView**](https://encryptedpixel.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/simple-accordion-menu-in-uitableview-with-expandcollapse-animation/)
- [**Expand and collapse a view**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151250/iphone-expand-and-collapse-a-uiview-programmatically)

And they will for `IPad` as well.