# Expand and collapse animation not working in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I am working on `UIView`. This view is expand and collapse on button click. Its working on **iOS<=5** but not working **iOS6**. Can you please correct my code or explain it.

Thanks.

My Code:

```
    CGFloat x= 60,y = 391,w1=210,h1=48;
    [ViewShare setHidden:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationOff" context:NULL]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    [ViewShare setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w1, h1)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

And [Ref Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151250/iphone-expand-and-collapse-a-uiview-programmatically)

Thanks..

Comment: Where are you un-hiding "ViewShare"?

Comment: its view name ...
hidden on view didload

Comment: The animation won't work if it is hidden.You won't see it happening if you set ViewShare to hidden right before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mani, you should use the block based animation instead, because the use of commit animation is discouraged after iOS 4.0.

There is lot of GUI bug code if you try to cross lot of IOS, and try to use "deprecated" method. By the way your code is correct.

If you don't use IOS before 4.0, use instead

```
animateWithDuration:animations:completion:
```

Here's an example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2f
     animations:^{
    [ViewShare setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 391, 210, 48)];
}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
    // what you want when the animation is done
}];
```

Note that sometime, you need to switch behavior depending on iOS version, it is very always GUI related. That make me very nervous. :)

Comment: Yes Mr. bonjour its working, view is expand and collapse, but not move my buttons.  i have 4 button on viewshare. :(